# Scrape images from a specific excel column with python

Tags: python-3.x

I found a code that extracts images from an excel sheet and stores them in a folder. it worked perfectly but the problem now is that code is just grabbing one cell. i want to grab the full column.

```
 #Importing the modules
import openpyxl
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader

#loading the Excel File and the sheet
pxl_doc = openpyxl.load_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
sheet = pxl_doc['Sheet_name']

#calling the image_loader
image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet)

#get the image (put the cell you need instead of 'A1')
image = image_loader.get('A1')

#showing the image
image.show()

#saving the image
image.save('my_path/image_name.jpg')
```

Comment: What is preventing you from modifying this code?

Comment: I tried to set range of cells but i got error

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through cells as follows: A1, A2, A3....

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader

#loading the Excel File and the sheet
pxl_doc = openpyxl.load_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
sheet = pxl_doc['Sheet_name']

#calling the image_loader
image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet)

#get the image (put the cell you need instead of 'A1')
number_of_images = # put the number of your total images
for i in range(1, number_of_image+1):
    image = image_loader.get('A'+str(i))

    #saving the image
    image.save('my_path/image_name.jpg')
```

Assign the total number of rows *(images)* for the variable `number_of_images`. I suspect that you are still a beginner in python since you haven't thought about it, you should start learning about [loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) and [data concatenation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp).

Comment: Thanks for your assist.
actually, I am a beginner I've tried looping but couldn't make it correctly.
I've tried your code but gave me this error "ValueError: Cell C21 doesn't contain an image" although cell C21 contains an image !!!
also, i tried this code on another sheet and got the same error "ValueError: Cell C21 doesn't contain an image"

Comment: @ahmedsayed I can't get to say more as I don't see the code execution in front of me. But you can use `try` and `except` in order to handle the errors and continue looping for the next cell even though the error occurred.